# Could not match polymorphic type in haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I am not sure why `k4` below does not work, when `k3` does, its enough polymorphic. The error in `ghci` is

> ```
> • Couldn't match type ‘K' a0 a0’ with ‘End K'’
>   Expected type: K' a0 a0 -> K'' a a
> ```

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --install-ghc --resolver lts-8.21 runghc --package http-conduit --package lens
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, RankNTypes #-}

module YonedaLan where

type End g = forall a. g a a 

data K'  b c = K'
data K'' b c = K''

k1 :: () -> End K'
k1 x = K'

k2 :: End K' -> End K''
k2 x = case x of (K') -> K''

k3 :: () -> End K''
k3 x = k2 ( k1 x)

k4 :: () -> End K''
k4 = k2 . k1
```

Beside not writing point free style, is there some best practice for dealing with this ?

Comment: Type inference will never infer a polymorphic type. In the pointfree version, you need a type variable in the type of `(.)` to be inferred as `End K'` which is a polytype. Hence the error.

Comment: Furthermore to chi's point, is there any type `T` such that `((.) :: T) k2 k1` type checks?

Comment: @erisco T would cause the same instantiation. I used `(.) @ ...` to the same aim, and GHC told me "no impredicativity, please". I believe this can't be made to work.

Comment: @chi this looks like an answer.  (with impredicativity, it could somehow pass along the 'freeness' of variables along composition ?)

Comment: one trick I use now : since polymorphism is easily destroyed, I capture it in a GADT constructor `Forall`, applied, in an auxiliary fonction, directly (no composition) to the polymorphic result of the original fonction... not sure it's the most elegant but that makes it sane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the GHC type system will never instantiate a type variable to a polymorphic type. Doing that would require impredicativity in the type system.

In your concrete example, we have

```
(.) :: (b->c) -> (a->b) -> (a->c)
```

and, to type check `k2 . k1` we would need to instantiate `b ~ End K'` which is a polymorphic type.

A typical workaround would be to make `End K'` into a monomorphic type which wraps a polymorphic type. E.g.

```
newtype End g = End { unEnd :: forall a. g a a }
```

The price to pay is to explicitly wrap / unwrap values of type `End g` at every usage. This can also be mitigated exploiting GHC's "safe coercions".

Note that some other languages (like Agda, Coq, Idris) would handle your code (suitably translated) just fine, since they have an impredicative type system. However, their inference machinery are different from Haskell -- impredicativity makes it far harder. Sometimes, if not often, the type inference engine can't find the implicit type arguments, and types have to be explicitly provided.